# batch edit MacOS comment metadata 'MDItemFinderComment'

Tags: macos, metadata

Is there a way to batch edit MacOS comment metadata 'MDItemFinderComment'?

For example I have multiple files with comment like this:

```
file 1 apple NEW
file 2 orange NEW
file 3 grape NEW
```

I would like to batch remove the word 'NEW' from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/), you could use this command:

```
exiftool '-MDItemFinderComment<${MDItemFinderComment;s/ NEW$//}' /path/to/files/
```

This command applies regex to strip away `(space)NEW` from the end of the `MDItemFinderComment` in all files in the target directory. Add the [`-r` (`-recurse`) option](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories

Comment: That looks good, but I wonder if it can be tightened up a little with word boundaries before and after the word "NEW"? As it is, I think it might fail to do anything if the comment starts with "NEW" without a preceding space. And I think it might incorrectly change "SCIENTIST NEWTON" into "SCIENTIST TON". It is using Perl PCREs isn't it?

Comment: I *"think"* it *"might"* be better with `s/\wNEW\w//`

Comment: `\w` is word character, so that would require a `A-Za-z0-9_` before and after `NEW`.  `\b` is word boundary.    Assuming that `NEW` always appears a the end, adding the end of line marker would be better.  Editing answer to add this.

Comment: Also trying to make sure there is not a trailing space, which probably doesn't matter overall, just something of an annoyance to me.  And yes, exiftool is written in Perl, so it uses PCRE.

Comment: You already have my upvote. Thank you for thinking further about it and taking the time to clarify - appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @StarGeek for your help! It works perfectly!

I have another question. If I need to delete a longer string of text from the comment box, maybe a string of url with this variables `/ - ? = & ~`, replacing 'NEW' with the url doesn't work, so what should it be? For example to delete `/crop/x0+0/optimize?Name=abc__&Num=123~789__&Key-Id=XYZ` from `image.jpg/crop/x0+0/optimize?Name=abc__&Num=123~789__&Key-Id=XYZ`

Comment: The problem there is that a lot of those characters have special meanings in regular expressions (RegEx).  Any of these characters requires a backslash to escape it `. ^ $ * + - ? ( ) [ ] { } \ | — /`  (see [this StackOverflow answer and the one that follows it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760851/3525475))  So you would use `${MDItemFinderComment;s/\/crop\/x0\+0\/optimize\?Name\=abc__\&Num\=123\~789__\&Key\-Id\=XYZ$//}` instead.

Comment: Just realized that the equal signs were escaped in the above while they probably don't need to be.  That's because I used the Perl `quotemeta()` function in a quick & dirty way to escape your string.  `perl -e "print quotemeta('StringToEscape');"`  It won't hurt anything to escape characters that don't need escaping.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was missing a \ at the start when I manually added them in. `perl` helped me to make sure nothing is missing